# SettingWithCopy Pandas Division Warning

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have been struggling to find a way to create a new column in a DataFrame by dividing two columns by each other. It always throws the SettingWithCopy warning, no matter how I try to do it. Here are some examples:

```
school['overall_percent'] = (school['Overall Points'].div(school['Overall Possible'].values, axis='index')).values

school['overall_percent'] = school['Overall Points']/school['Overall Possible']

school['overall_percent'] = school['Overall Points']/school['Overall Possible'].values
```

What am I missing, and how do I ensure that I am not setting with a copy? I found the documentation to be a bit cryptic in this regard, it says what the problem is but the solution doesn't seem to be there.

Comment: Why dont use `school['overall_percent'] = school['Overall Points'].div(school['Overall Possible'])` ?

Comment: You need to post raw data, your code to create the df, your erroneous code and desired output. Basically it depends on what `school` actual is at this point as you have have filtered or taken a slice prior to your calling code

Comment: school_unfiltered = pd.read_csv("grades_2014.csv")
school = school_unfiltered[school_unfiltered['Overall Possible'] != 0]
school.reset_index(inplace=True)

Answer (score 0):

I (thought) I (had) discovered the error of my ways. I was trying to fix what was on the right side of this code, but the problem was the left side. So when I changed it to this:

```
school.loc['overall_percent',:] = ((school['Overall Points'].div(school['Overall Possible'].values, axis='index')).iloc[:])*100
```

When I caught another unrelated error, I found that this was adding an index to the row, and not making the change I needed. I'm back to that annoying SettingWithCopy warning.

Comment: But did that work though? This just hides the warning but it depends on your intent. Are you wanting to modify a view, i.e. the original df, or do you want to modify a copy?

Comment: I'm interested in adding a new column named 'overall_percent'. I'm not interested in changing the other columns, I would rather leave them be.

Comment: just change it to `school.loc[:, 'overall_percent']`. SettingWithCopy is a warning which is thrown by pandas when you try to write to a view of a dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

The root of the problem is in how the `school` dataframe was created. Pasting below the code used to load the data from one of your comments:

```py
school_unfiltered = pd.read_csv("grades_2014.csv")
school = school_unfiltered[school_unfiltered['Overall Possible'] != 0]
school.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

When `school` is created from `school_unfiltered` in this fashion, pandas stores a weak reference to the original dataframe. The SettingWithCopy warning is there because when you created the `overall_percent` column in `school`, pandas isn't sure if you want the column to be created in `school_unfiltered` as well.

I'm guessing that you don't a corresponding `overall_percent` column in `school_unfiltered`. In that case, creating `school` as an explicit copy of `school_unfiltered` should negate further SettingWithCopy warnings.

```py
school = school_unfiltered[school_unfiltered['Overall Possible'] != 0].copy()
```

Ref:

1. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
2. https://tnwei.github.io/posts/settings-with-copy-warning-pandas/